# libdash mpd parser integration with custom player

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, media-player, mpeg-dash

I have written a multimedia player using ffmpeg and qt-framework. And currently I support local file playback and progressive download playback in my player. Now I want to add support for mpeg-dash vod stream playback. I thought of using [libdash](https://github.com/bitmovin/libdash) opensource dash library. But after so much of googling I couldn't find any API or developer documentation regarding the same.

Also another issue is libdash has integrated network module. But I want only mpd parser to be integrated and I have my own network module for downloading. I couln't find any doxygen and usage documentation for libdash.

I need help in these:

1. Can you anyone point me to any developer documentation available for
   libdash?
2. Is there any alternative library for libdash?

Answer (score 1):

The source contains a doxygen config and you could create the doxygen documentation by your own through:

doxygen [libdash_doxygen_config](https://github.com/bitmovin/libdash/blob/master/libdash_doxygen_config)

There is no need to use the network components of libdash you can use your own as for example shown in the [HTTP2 branch](https://github.com/bitmovin/libdash/tree/http2), which shows how to use libdash with HTTP2. Basically you just need to implement your own Connection that implements the [IConnection](https://github.com/bitmovin/libdash/blob/master/libdash/libdash/include/IConnection.h) interface. The [IDownloadableChunk](https://github.com/bitmovin/libdash/blob/master/libdash/libdash/include/IDownloadableChunk.h) interface allows you then to pass your own connection to libdash for segment download through *StartDownload (IConnection *connection)*.

Comment: Thank u so much for the info. I will try this and get back to u.